# Run Redis or Memcached as root or non-root?

Tags: linux, redis, memcached, root

Does it matter if I run Redis or Memcached as root or non-root?

I'm thinking of creating a non-sudo Redis/Memcached user, and running the cache as that user. I would make all files owned by that non-sudo user. What would be the pros and cons of such a setup?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is able to write file ! Running him as root is a BIG security issue.
More info on https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3594

Answer (score -1):

There should be no consequences as long as the directories and files used by Redis are all accessible by non-root user.